# Trying to make my camera sit behind the character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my camera to sit behind my player. Currently, it follows the "tracker" which is a child object attached to the player but it doesn't follow relative to the character's rotation.
The camera rotates fine which just locks its view onto the tracker.
The offset is set manually in the script (inspector).
code:

```
private void cam_movement(GameObject tracker, bool tracking) {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, tracker.transform.position + camera_offset, follow_speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfCHe.png)
I removed the camera tracking's rotation code.

Comment: Have you tried with a LookAt and look the character?

Comment: My camera looks at the character correctly the problem is with the offset. Im trying to keep the offset always behind the player.

Comment: I have to seriously recomend you look into Cinemachine! It will do all this for you and, after a *very* small learning curve, is quite simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tracker gives the offset, why do you need another offset to the offset (`camera_offset`)? Or is the tracker the focus point that you aim the camera at?

Presumably, `camera_offset` is in world-space coordinates (given that you're adding it to `.position`), but you're probably thinking of it in object local-space coordinates.

Thus,

```
private void cam_movement(GameObject tracker, bool tracking) {
    // convert offset from local- to world-space
    var camera_worldOffset = tracker.transform.transformVector(camera_offset);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, tracker.transform.position + camera_worldOffset, follow_speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **Cinemachine** instead of the default camera? It's much easier

Comment: Trying to do it myself so I can learn a bit